# Is a cache available for all identical queries in a rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my index I call

```
<% Shoes.roots.each do |shoe| %>
    <%= link_to shoe.shoe_name, shoe %>
<% end %>
```

I have a some html organizing the page and later call:

```
<% Shoe.roots.each do |shoe| %>    
  <%= link_to shoe.shoe_name, shoe %>
  <%= shoe.shoe_size %>
<% end %>
```

To provide some links and shoe sizes.

I'm using rack-mini-profiler and it shows me that I am not doing two separate queries. If I cache the top .each do:

```
<% Shoes.roots.each do |shoe| %>
  <% cache(shoe) do %>
    <%= link_to shoe.shoe_name, shoe %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Is the bottom one also cached even though I don't use shoe.shoe_size in the top .each do? Would it work the opposite way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails does cache SQL queries. If the query is identical within the same request, it will not execute the same request again.

You should consider assigning your shoes to an instance variable in the controller:

```
@roots = Shoe.roots
```

and then in the views access that variable

```
<% @roots.each do |shoe| %>
    <%= link_to shoe.shoe_name, shoe %>
<% end %>

<% @roots.each do |shoe| %>    
  <%= link_to shoe.shoe_name, shoe %>
  <%= shoe.shoe_size %>
<% end %>
```